# Who was Elliot speaking to?

Tags: mr-robot

S02E04 of Mr. Robot, approximately 48 minutes in, Elliot says:

> Even make amends with those who I have unfairly wronged

And hugs this man:

[image]

[image]

Who was he speaking to, and what is the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While finishing the episode, I remembered who it was:

From S01E05, Elliot is forced to belittle (the scene was horrifying to watch) him:

[image]

> Elliot: Think about it, Bill.
>
> Bill: Think about what?
>
> Elliot: If you died, would anyone care? Would they really care? Yeah, maybe they'd cry for a day, but,
>   let's be honest, no one would give a shit. They wouldn't. The few
>   people that would feel obligated to go to your funeral would probably
>   be annoyed and leave as early as possible. That's who you are, that's
>   what you are. You're nothing to anyone. To everyone. Think about it,
>   Bill. Because if you do, if you let yourself, you'll know I'm telling
>   you the truth. So, instead of wasting any more of my time, I need you
>   to go call someone that matters. Because, Bill You don't.
>
> Bill: I'll, um
>   I'll call my supervisor.